# How do i use nunjuck environments in side an express application for global variables?

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

Im a little stuck and was wondering if somebody could help me please.

I have an express application and i want to add global variables to the nunjucks rendering engine.

Im aware of the nunjucks addGlobal (http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#addglobal) method docs here but do not know how to tie an environment into my current config block. As it appears to not be functioning i assume its something to do with my setup.

Here is what i have for my config setup:

```
const viewFolders = [
  path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views')
];

// *** view engine *** //
nunjucks.configure(viewFolders, {
  express: app,
  autoescape: true
});
var env = new nunjucks.Environment(new nunjucks.FileSystemLoader('views'));
console.log(env);
env.addGlobal('logged_in','FROM Module');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

As you can see i followed the docs and in my template i have {{logged_in}} but it does not show anything. Now my other render variables work fine. But i think i need to somehow link my env to my nunjucks configuration ?

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Ill be sure to update you if i make any more progress but i have been trying for a full day now so if anyone can spot the issue i would thank you greatly.

Thanks in advance for any help i get.

Comment: All `res.locals`-variables available in templates. You can put global vars to `res.locals` in some middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals):

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).

Comment: Btw in case this is not clear all res.locals can be used inside the templates.

Answer (score 0):

So with the configuration block. You need to set it to a variable and then reference that in order to set global variables.

eg.

```
var env;
env = nunjucks.configure(viewFolders, {
  express: app,
  autoescape: true
});
env.addGlobal('logged_in','FROM Module');
```

Comment: If you are using a similar config to something like mine. You may want to add it to the app object. eg: app.nunjucks_env

Then i need to check if there is a user so i can just use the app.use to register middleware that checks if the user is present and set my global variables happily in any of my templates.